# Why would a stored procedure never return until the timeout kicks in when the actual code of the SP when executed directly returns in 10 minutes?

Tags: mysql

We have a stored procedure (code attached). When the contents of that SP are run from the client (i.e a large block of SQL executed directly) it always returns in 10minutes. When a CALL is used for the stored procedure very occasionally it returns in 10 minutes but generally never returns (and finally the connection is timed-out).

On the server there seems to be no activity going on after 10 mins (as if it has finished but just not notified the client). Some of the individual queries in the SP take longer than the slow query threshold (60s) and those are logged as expected during the SP execution. If we reduce the size of the SP by removing some of the final few statements it returns...but executing just those last few statements works fine. This SP works fine on the existing server  (5.5) but not on the 'new' server (5.6) - why we have to be on 5.6 is out of scope of this question. Ideally we cannot change the SP - it is production legacy code. What can we investigate, log, dig into to resolve this or provide useful information as to what is going on? Anyone else seen this - I never have before!

```
DELIMITER ;;
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`%` PROCEDURE `GPN_CREATE_PAYMENT_AGGREGATES`()
COMMENT 'A procedure to create aggregated payment values'
BEGIN 

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS LAST_ONE_OFF_VALUES;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE LAST_ONE_OFF_VALUES AS (
SELECT
OPERATION_TRANSACTION.CONSTITUENT_ID,
AMOUNT AS LAST_ONE_OFF_AMOUNT,
VENTURE_CODE AS LAST_ONE_OFF_VC
FROM 
OPERATION_TRANSACTION, CONSTITUENT 
WHERE OPERATION_TRANSACTION.CONSTITUENT_ID = CONSTITUENT.CONSTITUENT_ID
AND TRANSACTION_STATUS = 'SU'
AND PAYMENT_METHOD != 'DD'
AND OPERATION_DATE = LAST_ONE_OFF_PAYMENT
)  ;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS AVERAGE_PAYMENT_VALUES;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE AVERAGE_PAYMENT_VALUES AS (
SELECT
CONSTITUENT_ID,
AVG(AMOUNT) AS AVERAGE_PAYMENT_SUM_2Y
FROM 
OPERATION_TRANSACTION 
WHERE TRANSACTION_STATUS = 'SU',
AND TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, OPERATION_DATE, CURDATE()) < 2
GROUP BY CONSTITUENT_ID
)  ;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS MAX_PAYMENT_VALUES;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE MAX_PAYMENT_VALUES AS (
SELECT
CONSTITUENT_ID,
MAX(AMOUNT) AS MAX_PAYMENT_SUM_3Y
FROM 
OPERATION_TRANSACTION 
WHERE TRANSACTION_STATUS = 'SU'
AND TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, OPERATION_DATE, CURDATE()) < 3
GROUP BY CONSTITUENT_ID
)  ;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS AVERAGE_12M_ONEOFF_VALUES;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE AVERAGE_12M_ONEOFF_VALUES AS (
SELECT
CONSTITUENT_ID,
AVG(AMOUNT) AS AVERAGE_ONEOFF_SUM_12M
FROM 
OPERATION_TRANSACTION 
WHERE TRANSACTION_STATUS = 'SU'
AND TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, OPERATION_DATE, CURDATE()) < 1
AND PAYMENT_METHOD != 'DD'
GROUP BY CONSTITUENT_ID
)  ;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS MAX_ONEOFF_VALUES;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE MAX_ONEOFF_VALUES AS (
SELECT
CONSTITUENT_ID,
MAX(AMOUNT) AS MAX_ONEOFF_SUM_3Y
FROM 
OPERATION_TRANSACTION 
WHERE TRANSACTION_STATUS = 'SU'
AND TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, OPERATION_DATE, CURDATE()) < 3
AND PAYMENT_METHOD != 'DD'
GROUP BY CONSTITUENT_ID
)  ;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS DD_YTD_VALUES;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE DD_YTD_VALUES AS (
SELECT
CONSTITUENT_ID,
COUNT(*) AS NUM_OF_DD_PAYMENTS_YTD,
SUM(AMOUNT) AS SUM_OF_DD_PAYMENTS_YTD
FROM 
OPERATION_TRANSACTION 
WHERE TRANSACTION_STATUS = 'SU'
AND YEAR(OPERATION_DATE) = YEAR(CURDATE())
AND PAYMENT_METHOD = 'DD'
GROUP BY CONSTITUENT_ID
)  ;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS OO_YTD_VALUES;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE OO_YTD_VALUES AS (
SELECT
CONSTITUENT_ID,
COUNT(*) AS NUM_OF_OO_PAYMENTS_YTD,
SUM(AMOUNT) AS SUM_OF_OO_PAYMENTS_YTD
FROM 
OPERATION_TRANSACTION 
WHERE TRANSACTION_STATUS = 'SU'
AND YEAR(OPERATION_DATE) = YEAR(CURDATE())
AND PAYMENT_METHOD != 'DD'
GROUP BY CONSTITUENT_ID
)  ;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS YTD_VALUES;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE YTD_VALUES AS (
SELECT
CONSTITUENT_ID,
COUNT(*) AS NUM_OF_PAYMENTS_YTD,
SUM(AMOUNT) AS SUM_OF_PAYMENTS_YTD
FROM 
OPERATION_TRANSACTION 
WHERE TRANSACTION_STATUS = 'SU'
AND YEAR(OPERATION_DATE) = YEAR(CURDATE())
GROUP BY CONSTITUENT_ID
)  ;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS DD_12M_VALUES;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE DD_12M_VALUES AS (
SELECT
CONSTITUENT_ID,
COUNT(*) AS NUM_OF_DD_PAYMENTS_12M,
SUM(AMOUNT) AS SUM_OF_DD_PAYMENTS_12M
FROM 
OPERATION_TRANSACTION 
WHERE TRANSACTION_STATUS = 'SU'
AND TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, OPERATION_DATE, CURDATE()) < 1
AND PAYMENT_METHOD = 'DD'
GROUP BY CONSTITUENT_ID
)  ;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS OO_12M_VALUES;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE OO_12M_VALUES AS (
SELECT
CONSTITUENT_ID,
COUNT(*) AS NUM_OF_OO_PAYMENTS_12M,
SUM(AMOUNT) AS SUM_OF_OO_PAYMENTS_12M
FROM 
OPERATION_TRANSACTION 
WHERE TRANSACTION_STATUS = 'SU'
AND TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, OPERATION_DATE, CURDATE()) < 1
AND PAYMENT_METHOD != 'DD'
GROUP BY CONSTITUENT_ID
)  ;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS A12M_VALUES;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE A12M_VALUES AS (
SELECT
CONSTITUENT_ID,
COUNT(*) AS NUM_OF_PAYMENTS_12M,
SUM(AMOUNT) AS SUM_OF_PAYMENTS_12M
FROM 
OPERATION_TRANSACTION 
WHERE TRANSACTION_STATUS = 'SU'
AND TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, OPERATION_DATE, CURDATE()) < 1
GROUP BY CONSTITUENT_ID
)  ;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS DD_24M_VALUES;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE DD_24M_VALUES AS (
SELECT
CONSTITUENT_ID,
COUNT(*) AS NUM_OF_DD_PAYMENTS_24M,
SUM(AMOUNT) AS SUM_OF_DD_PAYMENTS_24M
FROM 
OPERATION_TRANSACTION 
WHERE TRANSACTION_STATUS = 'SU'
AND TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, OPERATION_DATE, CURDATE()) < 2
AND PAYMENT_METHOD = 'DD'
GROUP BY CONSTITUENT_ID
)  ;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS OO_24M_VALUES;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE OO_24M_VALUES AS (
SELECT
CONSTITUENT_ID,
COUNT(*) AS NUM_OF_OO_PAYMENTS_24M,
SUM(AMOUNT) AS SUM_OF_OO_PAYMENTS_24M
FROM 
OPERATION_TRANSACTION 
WHERE TRANSACTION_STATUS = 'SU'
AND TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, OPERATION_DATE, CURDATE()) < 2
AND PAYMENT_METHOD != 'DD'
GROUP BY CONSTITUENT_ID
)  ;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS A24M_VALUES;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE A24M_VALUES AS (
SELECT
CONSTITUENT_ID,
COUNT(*) AS NUM_OF_PAYMENTS_24M,
SUM(AMOUNT) AS SUM_OF_PAYMENTS_24M
FROM 
OPERATION_TRANSACTION 
WHERE TRANSACTION_STATUS = 'SU'
AND TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, OPERATION_DATE, CURDATE()) < 2
GROUP BY CONSTITUENT_ID
)  ;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS LAST_SAVE_DATES;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE LAST_SAVE_DATES AS (
SELECT
CONSTITUENT_ID,
MAX(OPERATION_DATE) AS LAST_SAVE_DATE
FROM
COMMUNICATION
WHERE OPERATION_CODE = '90001'
GROUP BY CONSTITUENT_ID
)  ;

SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES=0;
UPDATE CONSTITUENT
SET
LAST_ONE_OFF_AMOUNT = NULL, LAST_ONE_OFF_VC = NULL, AVERAGE_PAYMENT_SUM_2Y = NULL, MAX_PAYMENT_SUM_3Y = NULL, AVERAGE_ONEOFF_SUM_12M = NULL, MAX_ONEOFF_SUM_3Y = NULL,
NUM_OF_DD_PAYMENTS_YTD = 0, SUM_OF_DD_PAYMENTS_YTD = NULL, NUM_OF_OO_PAYMENTS_YTD = 0, SUM_OF_OO_PAYMENTS_YTD = NULL,
NUM_OF_PAYMENTS_YTD = 0, SUM_OF_PAYMENTS_YTD = NULL,
NUM_OF_DD_PAYMENTS_12M = 0, SUM_OF_DD_PAYMENTS_12M = NULL, NUM_OF_OO_PAYMENTS_12M = 0, SUM_OF_OO_PAYMENTS_12M = NULL,
NUM_OF_PAYMENTS_12M = 0, SUM_OF_PAYMENTS_12M = NULL,
NUM_OF_DD_PAYMENTS_24M = 0, SUM_OF_DD_PAYMENTS_24M = NULL, NUM_OF_OO_PAYMENTS_24M = 0, SUM_OF_OO_PAYMENTS_24M = NULL,
NUM_OF_PAYMENTS_24M = 0, SUM_OF_PAYMENTS_24M = NULL, LAST_SAVE_DATE = NULL;


UPDATE CONSTITUENT, (SELECT * FROM LAST_ONE_OFF_VALUES) src 
SET CONSTITUENT.LAST_ONE_OFF_AMOUNT = src.LAST_ONE_OFF_AMOUNT,
CONSTITUENT.LAST_ONE_OFF_VC = src.LAST_ONE_OFF_VC
where CONSTITUENT.CONSTITUENT_ID=src.CONSTITUENT_ID;

UPDATE CONSTITUENT, (SELECT * FROM AVERAGE_PAYMENT_VALUES) src2 
SET CONSTITUENT.AVERAGE_PAYMENT_SUM_2Y = src2.AVERAGE_PAYMENT_SUM_2Y
where CONSTITUENT.CONSTITUENT_ID=src2.CONSTITUENT_ID;

UPDATE CONSTITUENT, (SELECT * FROM MAX_PAYMENT_VALUES) src3 
SET CONSTITUENT.MAX_PAYMENT_SUM_3Y = src3.MAX_PAYMENT_SUM_3Y
where CONSTITUENT.CONSTITUENT_ID=src3.CONSTITUENT_ID;

UPDATE CONSTITUENT, (SELECT * FROM AVERAGE_12M_ONEOFF_VALUES) src4 
SET CONSTITUENT.AVERAGE_ONEOFF_SUM_12M = src4.AVERAGE_ONEOFF_SUM_12M
where CONSTITUENT.CONSTITUENT_ID=src4.CONSTITUENT_ID;

UPDATE CONSTITUENT, (SELECT * FROM MAX_ONEOFF_VALUES) src5 
SET CONSTITUENT.MAX_ONEOFF_SUM_3Y = src5.MAX_ONEOFF_SUM_3Y
where CONSTITUENT.CONSTITUENT_ID=src5.CONSTITUENT_ID;

UPDATE CONSTITUENT, (SELECT * FROM DD_YTD_VALUES) src6 
SET CONSTITUENT.NUM_OF_DD_PAYMENTS_YTD = src6.NUM_OF_DD_PAYMENTS_YTD,
CONSTITUENT.SUM_OF_DD_PAYMENTS_YTD = src6.SUM_OF_DD_PAYMENTS_YTD
where CONSTITUENT.CONSTITUENT_ID=src6.CONSTITUENT_ID;

UPDATE CONSTITUENT, (SELECT * FROM OO_YTD_VALUES) src7 
SET CONSTITUENT.NUM_OF_OO_PAYMENTS_YTD = src7.NUM_OF_OO_PAYMENTS_YTD,
CONSTITUENT.SUM_OF_OO_PAYMENTS_YTD = src7.SUM_OF_OO_PAYMENTS_YTD
where CONSTITUENT.CONSTITUENT_ID=src7.CONSTITUENT_ID;

UPDATE CONSTITUENT, (SELECT * FROM YTD_VALUES) src8 
SET CONSTITUENT.NUM_OF_PAYMENTS_YTD = src8.NUM_OF_PAYMENTS_YTD,
CONSTITUENT.SUM_OF_PAYMENTS_YTD = src8.SUM_OF_PAYMENTS_YTD
where CONSTITUENT.CONSTITUENT_ID=src8.CONSTITUENT_ID;

UPDATE CONSTITUENT, (SELECT * FROM DD_12M_VALUES) src9 
SET CONSTITUENT.NUM_OF_DD_PAYMENTS_12M = src9.NUM_OF_DD_PAYMENTS_12M,
CONSTITUENT.SUM_OF_DD_PAYMENTS_12M = src9.SUM_OF_DD_PAYMENTS_12M
where CONSTITUENT.CONSTITUENT_ID=src9.CONSTITUENT_ID;

UPDATE CONSTITUENT, (SELECT * FROM OO_12M_VALUES) src10 
SET CONSTITUENT.NUM_OF_OO_PAYMENTS_12M = src10.NUM_OF_OO_PAYMENTS_12M,
CONSTITUENT.SUM_OF_OO_PAYMENTS_12M = src10.SUM_OF_OO_PAYMENTS_12M
where CONSTITUENT.CONSTITUENT_ID=src10.CONSTITUENT_ID;

UPDATE CONSTITUENT, (SELECT * FROM A12M_VALUES) src11 
SET CONSTITUENT.NUM_OF_PAYMENTS_12M = src11.NUM_OF_PAYMENTS_12M,
CONSTITUENT.SUM_OF_PAYMENTS_12M = src11.SUM_OF_PAYMENTS_12M
where CONSTITUENT.CONSTITUENT_ID=src11.CONSTITUENT_ID;

UPDATE CONSTITUENT, (SELECT * FROM DD_24M_VALUES) src12 
SET CONSTITUENT.NUM_OF_DD_PAYMENTS_24M = src12.NUM_OF_DD_PAYMENTS_24M,
CONSTITUENT.SUM_OF_DD_PAYMENTS_24M = src12.SUM_OF_DD_PAYMENTS_24M
where CONSTITUENT.CONSTITUENT_ID=src12.CONSTITUENT_ID;

UPDATE CONSTITUENT, (SELECT * FROM OO_24M_VALUES) src13 
SET CONSTITUENT.NUM_OF_OO_PAYMENTS_24M = src13.NUM_OF_OO_PAYMENTS_24M,
CONSTITUENT.SUM_OF_OO_PAYMENTS_24M = src13.SUM_OF_OO_PAYMENTS_24M
where CONSTITUENT.CONSTITUENT_ID=src13.CONSTITUENT_ID;

UPDATE CONSTITUENT, (SELECT * FROM A24M_VALUES) src14 
SET CONSTITUENT.NUM_OF_PAYMENTS_24M = src14.NUM_OF_PAYMENTS_24M,
CONSTITUENT.SUM_OF_PAYMENTS_24M = src14.SUM_OF_PAYMENTS_24M
where CONSTITUENT.CONSTITUENT_ID=src14.CONSTITUENT_ID;

UPDATE CONSTITUENT, (SELECT * FROM LAST_SAVE_DATES) src15
SET CONSTITUENT.LAST_SAVE_DATE = src15.LAST_SAVE_DATE
where CONSTITUENT.CONSTITUENT_ID=src15.CONSTITUENT_ID;

SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES=1;

SELECT '1';
END;;
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Maybe take a look at the [processlist](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/show-processlist.html)?

Comment: Can you generate a (profile](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/show-profile.html)?

Comment: @GhostGambler yeah we had done that and weirdly although the client is still waiting the process list shows the process that was there all through the 10mins of SP execution time is now in command 'Sleep' with no state....ad just stays like that until the timeout kicks in eventually

Comment: To me this sounds like a bug, although without further investigation it is hard to tell for sure. My next step would be to try the most current mysql version. With some configuration it may be working for the old application and the issue might go away.

Comment: Just following this up to say that we see the same issue on MYSQL 5.7